# probability calculation with two independent normal RVs

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I don't understand why

```
Probability[X < Y, {X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1],
  Y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}]
```

gives 1/2

while we know that X/Y is Cauchy(0,1) and that

```
Probability[Z < 1, Z \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]
```

gives 3/4

I tried many different approaches and I can't figure out why we have this difference.

Comment: Try `Probability[Abs[x] <= 1, x \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]`?

Comment: kguler, this does not even run. I am trying to calculate P(X < Y), I just don't understand where the discrepancy is coming from. In fact, there should not be a reason to take absolute value since X, Y are independent and may be positive or negative

Comment: never mind, this worked: Probability[Z < 1 && Z > -1, 
 Z \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]

Comment: Probability[Abs[Z] < 1, Z \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]] ran fine for me, giving 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**

If $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ are independent, how come:

$$ P(X<Y) = \frac12  \quad \text{while}  \quad   P(\frac{X}{Y}<1) = \frac34$$

**Answer**

Nothing to do with Mma. The answer is that the rules of standard algebra do NOT apply to the *algebra of random variables*, so you cannot simply divide both parts of $P(X<Y)$ by $Y$ ... to get $P(\frac{X}{Y}<1)$ ... , which is what you seem to be doing. Note that $\frac{Y}{Y} \neq 1$, since this denotes the ratio of two random variables (not 2 fixed numbers).

Similarly: $P(X<0)   \neq  P(X^2<0) \quad$  (The former is $\frac12$; the latter is 0)

---

P.S. An easy solution to $P(X<Y)$ is:

- Let $Z = (X-Y) \sim N(0, 2)$.
- $P(X<Y) = P(X-Y<0) = P(Z<0) = \frac12$ .